# Tapjoy placement issue ads are not visible in App

Tags: ios, tapjoy

I am developing an app for iOS in which I need to integrate TapJoy SDK. All the things are done perfectly. Connection created successfully, Real time graph shows perfect result, but the issue is that the ads that are being created on "Create Placement" on App Launch are not visible in app. How can I get the TapJoy ads to appear?

Comment: Throw Tapjoy and use Chartboost, seriously I did same ha ha..simple fix na :D

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code, I'm flying blind, but this could be due to a few things: each of which you can verify in the debug output while your app is running.

1) This issue may be caused due to a race condition, where your app is executing the "[placementToShow requestContent];" call before your "[Tapjoy connect:@""];" call successfully connects to TapJoy or because it fails to connect to TapJoy.

2) This issue may be caused due to another race condition, where your app is executing the "[placementToShow showContentWithViewController:];" before your "[placementToShow requestContent];" successfully obtains/returns the content for your placement.

You can solve both of these problems by implementing a short 1 or 2 second delay in your app to allow the TapJoy connect & requestContent calls to succeed.

Comment: Thanks alot @Wilson. The issue was exactly same as u said. i put the code in activity and navigate it again and again. on third hit the tapjoy add become able to view. So then i fix it as standard manner. Again Bundle of thanks to help me as torch. :)

Comment: Awesome @SHAamirRafiq!  I'm glad it helped.  Please accept/mark my answer correct when you have a moment.  Good luck w/ your project!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Wilson is correct.

They way Tapjoy's SDK works, you must wait for the connect call to succeed before you start requesting content. Content requests made before the connect call succeeds will fail. Often, it is a good idea to use the connect call notification delegates to know when the connect call has succeeded:

http://dev.tapjoy.com/sdk-integration/ios/getting-started-guide-publishers-ios/#connect_call_notification_delegates

(Note: I'm with Tapjoy)